# Building sstp-client on Kali Linux from Source: dpkg errors

Tags: debian, kali-linux, vpn, dpkg, source

I am following the commands below--[modified from the answer here](https://serverfault.com/a/732740/404459)--in hopes of building a `.deb` package of `sstp-client` for my Kali Linux build. I eventually want a username/password-authenticated SSTP VPN option in the Gnome network-manager GUI.

I'm running these commands on the Kali Linux build, which is based on Debian, so--to my understanding--should work:

```
apt-get install build-essential dpkg-dev debhelper ppp-dev libevent-dev libssl-dev
mkdir sstp-client.build && cd sstp-client.build
wget 'http://sourceforge.net/projects/sstp-client/files/sstp-client/sstp-client-1.0.12.tar.gz'
tar -xzvf sstp-client-1.0.12
cd sstp-client-1.0.12
dpkg-buildpackage -b -us -uc
```

And this is where I run into an error:

`dpkg-buildpackage: error: cannot open file debian/changelog: No such file or directory`

---

After spotting some other `dpkg` commands on [this page](https://docs.kali.org/development/rebuilding-a-package-from-source), I decided to try `dpkg-checkbuilddeps`:

`dpkg-checkbuilddeps: error: cannot read debian/control: No such file or directory`

---

How can I move past these errors so I can build the `.deb` package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On debian testing, you can install `sstp-client` from this [git repository](https://github.com/enaess/network-manager-sstp).

> Attention Debian Users:
>
> Debian/Ubuntu users can now use my personal PPA to download and install the `network-manager-sstp` and `sstp-client` project via launchpad.

Using `apt` (`bionic` suite for debian testing):

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 61FF9694161CE595 
echo "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/eivnaes/network-manager-sstp/ubuntu bionic main" |sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sstp-client.list
sudo apt update
sudo apt install sstp-client
```

Comment: Hey, thanks so much! I didn't realize Kali Linux fell under the category of "debian testing." Did a reboot and the SSTP VPN option was right in the GUI Network settings. I can connect to my network-exclusive sites so seems to be working so far!